# Can Chrome Extension listen to key event without clicking the extension icon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

guys. I'd like some guidance to develop a Chrome's extension.

My Chrome's extension receives keycode to do something, but it only listen to event when I click the extension icon to open its DOM first.
I wonder if it can listen to key event from pages without clicking the icon first.

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "custom-shortcut",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>", "http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["./scripts/keyListener.js", "./scripts/background.js", "./scripts/constant.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Custom Shortcut"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["./scripts/background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You load background.js both as a background script and as a content script, which is totally wrong. You need to move the code that you want to run as a content script into a separate file.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really new to this.